# How should I construct a binary classifier for small set of positive data and million of unlabeled data?

Tags: classification, labeling, one-class

Does anyone have suggestions for specific algorithm or implementation for labeled data of only one class and unlabeled data that can be from either classes? And I'm unsure what is the proportion of Class A to B that exists within the unlabeled data and also my labeled data is not randomly chosen.

Comment: Not really.  You could try some clustering to see whether the labelled data tends to be clustered together, and if so guess that unlabelled data in the same cluster might more likely to be of the same class than unlabelled data in different clusters.  But you would have no idea to what extent this applied.  And it could lead you down the path of [Amazon's sexist résumé-screening tool](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-45809919) which had to be abandoned

Comment: @Henry Can you please explain why I cannot use one class classifier?